# how to get dynamic substring in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a scroll animation and want to get the transition value to a given time.

```
const transform = document.getElementsByClassName('slideContainer')[0].style.transform;
```

For example I get the following value: `translate(-2.51028%, 0%) translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)`

But I just want the `-2.51028%`

How do I do that?

Answer (score 4):

You could use `String.prototype.split()`:

```js
let str = "translate(-2.51028%, 0%) translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)"

console.log(str.split("(")[1].split(",")[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you might want to use a regular expression - they're great tools for matching patterns in strings. You can match the start of the string, followed by `translate(`, then capture as many non-comma characters as you can in a group. That group will have the substring you want:

```js
const transform = 'translate(-2.51028%, 0%) translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)';
const match = transform.match(/translate\(([^,]+)/);
// match[0] refers to the entire matched substring,
// match[1] will contain the first captured group:
console.log(match[1]);
```

Comment: So many people just hate regexes :). I wish I was better at it though...